# Is it possible to crop bottom of div/section using svg/png shape in html

Tags: html, css

I want to start new content right after end of svg/png arc shape. The empty transparent space should be filled by new div content (in other words one section should end with arc shape and other should start right after it keeping the empty (transparent) area below arc should be reserved by new section content).

```
<section style="background-image: url('pattern_1.jpg');">
    Content goes here...
    <img src="arc1.svg"/>
</section>
<section style="background-image: url('pattern_2.jpg');">
    Content goes here...
    <img src="arc2.svg"/>
</section>
<section style="background-image: url('pattern_3.jpg');">
    Content goes here...
    <img src="arc3.svg"/>
</section>
```

Here is the sample output that I want:
[image]

here is what I get right now:
[image]

It seems that I want to clip path using the arc.svg dynamically. I mean, user will add more sections (each section with different arc shape). and also how can we make it responsive when we don't know the upcoming arc shape.

Comment: @Jax-p, its not working in my case.. If you could suggest me how can I use it in my case that would be even better

Answer (score 1):

You can use [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) to clip elements (section) in some shape.
I created a **rough example** just to show how it could work:

```css
section { position: relative; }
section > div { min-height: 600px; }
section:not(:last-of-type) > div { clip-path: ellipse(125% 70% at 20% 0%); }
section + section { margin-top: -50%; }
.red { background-color: red; }
.blue { background-color: blue; }
section:not(:last-of-type):before {
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.2' viewBox='0 0 393 86'%3E%3Cpath fill='red' d='M-12 63s61-18.9 85-12c24 6.9 110 18.1 143 8C249 48.9 408-5 408-5v29S240.3 79.7 213 82C84 93-6 72.9-6 72.9z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 500;
}
```

```html
<section style="z-index: 3">
  <div style="background: black;">
    Content goes here...
  </div>
</section>

<section style="z-index: 2">
  <div style="background: gray;">
    Content goes here...
  </div>
</section>

<section style="z-index: 1">
  <div style="background: lightgray;">
    Content goes here...
  </div>
</section>
```

You can use online clip-path generators like [Clippy](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) to create custom shape.

Comment: isn't there a way to clip path using the arc.svg dynamically? I mean, user will add more sections (each section with different arc shape). and also how can we make it responsive when we don't know the upcoming arc shape

Comment: The above answer is not the solution I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

```css
*{
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
  }
  body{
    margin: 0px;
  }
  img{
    width: 100%;
  }
  section{
    position: relative;
  }
  section svg {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
  }

  section .arc-overlay {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
  }

  section .st0 {
      fill: transparent;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .content > div{
      display: block !important;
    }

    .content .cnt-1{
      max-width: 100% !important;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://demo.zhardsoft.com/arc-pattern/svg-inject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  
  SVGInject.setOptions({
      useCache: false, 
      copyAttributes: false,
      makeIdsUnique: false,
      afterInject: function(img, svg) {
        var svgElm=$(svg);
        var svgHeight=svgElm.height();
        svgElm.parents('section').css({'background-position-y':'-'+svgHeight+'px'});
        svgElm.parents('section').find('.arc-overlay').css({'height':svgHeight+'px','top':'-'+(svgHeight-1)+'px'});
        svgElm.parents('section').find('svg').css({'top':'-'+(svgHeight-1)+'px',});
      },
    });
  
  $(window).on('resize',function(){
    $('section svg').each(function(){
      var svgElm=$(this);
      var svgHeight=svgElm.height();
      svgElm.parents('section').css({'background-position-y':'-'+svgHeight+'px'});
      svgElm.parents('section').find('.arc-overlay').css({'height':svgHeight+'px','top':'-'+(svgHeight-1)+'px'});
      svgElm.parents('section').find('svg').css({'top':'-'+(svgHeight-1)+'px',});
    })
  })
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <section style="min-height: 500px;background-image: url(https://demo.zhardsoft.com/arc-pattern/wp2733014.jpg);background-size: 100% auto;">
      <div class="content" style="padding: 40px;padding-bottom: 150px">
        <div style="display: flex;display: -inline-flex;display: -webkit-flex;width: 100%">
          <div style="padding: 20px"><img src="https://demo.zhardsoft.com/arc-pattern/img1.png" style="width: 250px"></div>
          <div class="cnt-1" style="color: #EBEBEB;max-width: 50%">
            <h1>ECOLOGICAL PRODUCTION</h1>
          We recycle all organic waste we produce, also, we obtain organic waste from other farms, restaurants, and food markets. The organic waste we collect allows a particular larva from the Hermetia illucens species, known commonly as black soldier fly larva (BSFL), to feeds on it and grow fatter. When the larva has developed to a pupa, it is cleaned, cooked and grided to a paste used as a high-quality protein and lipids perfectly suited as ecological animal feed, reducing the need for wild-sourced feed ingredients such as fishmeal which contributes to the global overfishing.</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </section>
    <section style="min-height: 300px;background-image: url(https://demo.zhardsoft.com/arc-pattern/wp2732984.jpg);background-size: 100% auto;padding: 0 40px">
      <div class="content" style="padding: 20px;padding-bottom: 40px">
        <div style="display: flex;display: -inline-flex;display: -webkit-flex;width: 100%;justify-content: flex-end;">
          <div class="cnt-1" style="color: #EBEBEB;max-width: 50%;text-align: right;flex-grow: 1">
            <h1 style="color: #FDC403">LOCAL COMMUNITY<br>ENGAGEMENT.</h1>
          It is in our core believe that if you benefit the local community, the people there will add value to your business as well. For every site we establish a manufacturing facility, our project will add value to the community as whole. We will provide jobs for hundreds of local residents with positions available within our production, sales, administration, and management teams. We will also offer hundreds of local farmers opportunities to join our supply network, providing training, coaching, and financial support to help them adapt to a more intensive and efficient farming system. Through our research and development, anything learned or discovered will be shared with our farmers to produce more efficiently and a healthier product. One among many different local benefitting activities, is that we will arrange cleanup days where we offer students an extra income for their effort as well as courses in environment know-how and teach them the importance of keeping the environment healthy.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="arc-overlay" style="background-image: url(https://demo.zhardsoft.com/arc-pattern/wp2732984.jpg);background-size: 100% auto;-webkit-mask: url('https://demo.zhardsoft.com/arc-pattern/arc.svg') top/100% auto no-repeat"></div>
      <img src="https://demo.zhardsoft.com/arc-pattern/arc.svg" onload="SVGInject(this);"/>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

**For SVG**
Add a path under the arc in your SVG, to cover the bottom of the pattern. This is used to manipulate the background to match the pattern below it. for the above pattern no additional path is needed
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxsWV.png

the class name (path) in the SVG file must match the css style (.st0) you can change it with the class name you want.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhLa1.png

Comment: My technique is not by cropping the bottom of the div, but by manipulating the background at the bottom of the arc.

Comment: You should never set the default font-family for a document using the `*` universal selector. It is an inherited property, and you should be setting it in either the `html` or `body` selector.

Comment: Yes I know it can be instantiated on `html`, `body` or even elements. that's just an example I apply it universally

Comment: Since that is not where you should ever apply it, you shouldn't apply it that way in an example answer meant to teach people. There is no reason at all to ever use the `*` selector for font. Your answer would even be shorter adding it to your `body` selector. No reason to do it this way in an example or anywhere else.

Comment: Sometimes I do that when I want to apply to all elements without exception, it's up to you to do it my way or not. it's based on my experience only. since i used font-family in `body` tag, i have problem with sub element not covered

Comment: Hi Rahmat Dani! I can see your output is too close to what I want!
http://clawsandfins.com/sof_images/rehmat_dani_zaki.png

Could you please show us 3 sections with different arcs and background patterns
here is the link to arcs:
http://clawsandfins.com/sof_images/arcs/

Comment: Also please note: background pattern should not repeat itself and height should be adjusted with content dynamically (I noticed this issue in small screen)

Comment: Ok, I will make it and will update the code soon. Please wait

Comment: @AbdulHadi I have updated the code, please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/72472918/19218205

Answer (score 0):

```
<section class="bg-1">
  <img class="hero" src="hero.png" alt="" width="100%" height="auto">
  <img class="logo" src="logo.png" alt="" width="300px" height="auto">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1 class="title">We Are Using </h1>
        <h3 class="sub-title">High-tech and artificial intelligence (AI) To produce ecological food.</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="about-img" src="about.png" alt="Food" width="70%" height="auto">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <article class="about">
          <h2>About Us</h2>
          <p>
            Pete’s Claws and Fins is a high-tech producer of ecological seafood. We use state-of-the-art, highly computerized equipment to monitor and manage our seafood to ensure it is of the highest possible quality. All equipment we use is developed by ourselves in-house. We are the only company operating such high-tech equipment. The company started its research and development 2016 by Peter Persson, a Swedish inventor who has designed and built automated and computer-controlled machines and robots for over 30 years. Peter has over the years developed an increasing personal interest for natural and unprocessed food, and though he could make difference with help of his high-tech knowhow.
          </p>
        </article>
      </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>

<section class="bg-2">
  <img class="food" src="food-2.png" alt="" width="20%" height="auto">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <article class="">

          <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </p>
        </article>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <article class="">
          <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </p>
        </article>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <article class="">
          <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </p>
        </article>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <article class="">
          <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </p>
        </article>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <article class="">
          <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </p>
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="bg-3">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <article id="article-1">
          <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </p>
        </article>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <article id="article-2">
          <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </p>
        </article>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <article id="article-3">
          <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam
          </p>
        </article>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <article id="article-4">
          <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </p>
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <img class="food" src="food-2.png" alt="" width="20%" height="auto">
</section>
```

Comment: Code only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explaination, your answer is hard to understand.
If the OP can't understand your answer, then he also won't be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her. Please add a sufficient explaination of your possible solution.

Comment: No, using this code it is not possible,  to crop the bottom of div/section using svg/png shape in html. However, we used the customized backgrounds to separate sections. It may be an alternative way to design web pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
background: #999;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

```css
body{
    background: #999;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.logo{
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    z-index: 999;
}

.bg-1, .bg-2, .bg-3{
    padding: 100px 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: bottom;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
.bg-1{
    background-image: url(bg-111.png);
    padding-top: 0;
    z-index: 50;
}

.bg-2{
    background-image:url(bg-2.png);
    margin-top: -400px;
    padding-top: 500px;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
    z-index: 5;
}

.bg-3{
    background-image:url(bg-3.png);
    margin-top: -300px;
    padding-top: 400px;
    padding-bottom: 300px;
}

.bg-1 .title{
    color: #ffc602;
    font-size: 77px;
    margin-bottom: 50px:
}
.bg-1 .sub-title{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 34px;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.bg-2 .food{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 100px;
}
.bg-3 .food{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 100px;
    z-index: 200;
}

.about h2 {
    color: #ffc602;
    font-size: 55px;
    margin-bottom: 50px:
}
.about p {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.8;
    margin-bottom: 50px:
}

.article-1{
  padding: 100px;
  z-index: 10;
}

section{
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="bg-1">
      <img class="hero" src="hero.png" alt="" width="100%" height="auto">
      <img class="logo" src="logo.png" alt="" width="300px" height="auto">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1 class="title">We Are Using </h1>
            <h3 class="sub-title">High-tech and artificial intelligence (AI) To produce ecological food.</h3>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <img class="about-img" src="about.png" alt="Food" width="70%" height="auto">
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <article class="about">
              <h2>About Us</h2>
              <p>
                Pete’s Claws and Fins is a high-tech producer of ecological seafood. We use state-of-the-art, highly computerized equipment to monitor and manage our seafood to ensure it is of the highest possible quality. All equipment we use is developed by ourselves in-house. We are the only company operating such high-tech equipment. The company started its research and development 2016 by Peter Persson, a Swedish inventor who has designed and built automated and computer-controlled machines and robots for over 30 years. Peter has over the years developed an increasing personal interest for natural and unprocessed food, and though he could make difference with help of his high-tech knowhow.
              </p>
            </article>
          </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </section>

    <section class="bg-2">
      <img class="food" src="food-2.png" alt="" width="20%" height="auto">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <article class="">

              <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
              </p>
            </article>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <article class="">
              <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
              </p>
            </article>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <article class="">
              <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
              </p>
            </article>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <article class="">
              <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
              </p>
            </article>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <article class="">
              <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
              </p>
            </article>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="bg-3">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <article id="article-1">
              <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
              </p>
            </article>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <article id="article-2">
              <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
              </p>
            </article>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <article id="article-3">
              <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam
              </p>
            </article>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <article id="article-4">
              <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
              </p>
            </article>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <img class="food" src="food-2.png" alt="" width="20%" height="auto">
    </section>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explaination, your answer is hard to understand.
If the OP can't understand your answer, then he also won't be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her. Please add a sufficient explaination of your possible solution.

Comment: I couldn't understand this solution, it show the following output:
http://clawsandfins.com/sof_images/rabin_2.png

Answer (score 0):

```
  <body>
   
<!-- Main Section Start-->
    <div class="wrapper">
    <section class="header-img">
                 <img src="images/header-img.png" alt="header-image" title="header-image">
    </section>
    <section class="pattern_1 pattern">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 margin-b">
    <h1>We Are Using</h1>
    <p>High-tech and artificial intelligence (AI) To produce ecological food.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
    <img src="images/about-img.png" alt="about-img" title="about-img">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
     <h2>About Us</h2>
      <p>
        Pete’s Claws and Fins is a high-tech producer of ecological seafood. We use state-of-the-art, highly computerized equipment to monitor and manage our seafood to ensure it is of the highest possible quality. All equipment we use is developed by ourselves in-house. We are the only company operating such high-tech equipment. The company started its research and development 2016 by Peter Persson, a Swedish inventor who has designed and built automated and computer-controlled machines and robots for over 30 years. Peter has over the years developed an increasing personal interest for natural and unprocessed food, and though he could make difference with help of his high-tech knowhow.
      </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <img class="about-divider" src="images/about-bottom-img.png"/>
    </section>
    <section class="pattern_2 pattern"> 
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row margin-b">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
     <h2>Ecological Production</h2>
      <p>
        Pete’s Claws and Fins is a high-tech producer of ecological seafood. We use state-of-the-art, highly computerized equipment to monitor and manage our seafood to ensure it is of the highest possible quality. All equipment we use is developed by ourselves in-house. We are the only company operating such high-tech equipment. The company started its research and development 2016 by Peter Persson, a Swedish inventor who has designed and built automated and computer-controlled machines and robots for over 30 years. Peter has over the years developed an increasing personal interest for natural and unprocessed food, and though he could make difference with help of his high-tech knowhow.
      </p>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-center pattern-2img">
    <img src="images/about-img-02.png" alt="about-img" title="about-img">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5 text-center">
    <img src="images/about-img-03.png" alt="about-img" title="about-img">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <p>
        Pete’s Claws and Fins is a high-tech producer of ecological seafood. We use state-of-the-art, highly computerized equipment to monitor and manage our seafood to ensure it is of the highest possible quality. All equipment we use is developed by ourselves in-house. We are the only company operating such high-tech equipment. The company started its research and development 2016 by Peter Persson, a Swedish inventor who has designed and built automated and computer-controlled machines and robots for over 30 years. Peter has over the years developed an increasing personal interest for natural and unprocessed food, and though he could make difference with help of his high-tech knowhow.
      </p>
    </div>  
    </div>
    </div>
    <img class="about-divider" src="images/ecology-bottom-img.png"/>
    </section>
    <section class="pattern_3 pattern">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row margin-b">
    <div class="col-sm-8 pull-right text-r">
     <h2>Local Community Engagement.</h2>
      <p>
        Pete’s Claws and Fins is a high-tech producer of ecological seafood. We use state-of-the-art, highly computerized equipment to monitor and manage our seafood to ensure it is of the highest possible quality. All equipment we use is developed by ourselves in-house. We are the only company operating such high-tech equipment. The company started its research and development 2016 by Peter Persson, a Swedish inventor who has designed and built automated and computer-controlled machines and robots for over 30 years. Peter has over the years developed an increasing personal interest for natural and unprocessed food, and though he could make difference with help of his high-tech knowhow.
      </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </section>
    <section class="foote-img"> 
        <img class="circle-img" src="images/circle-img.png"/>
                 <img src="images/footer-img.png" alt="footer-img" title="footer-img">
    </section>
    </div>
<!--/Main Section End-->
</body>
```

Comment: I couldn't understand, here is what I see in your output:
http://clawsandfins.com/sof_images/user2334682.png

Answer (score 0):

```
  <section id="section_2" class="bg-2">
  <div class="section-2-bg">
    <!-- <h2>Section 2</h2> -->

    <div class="section-2-outer">

      <div id="section_2_inner" class="section-2-inner">

        <style media="screen">
          #section_2_inner {
            position: relative;
            background-image: url(pattern_2.jpg);
            padding: 300px 0px 120px;
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 600px;
            }
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          var height = document.getElementById('section_2_inner').offsetHeight;

          let radius7 = 40;

          if (height <= 650) {
            radius7 = 32 - (height - 400)/20;
          }else if (height <= 700) {
            radius7 = 45 - (height - 400)/20;
          }else if (height <= 1200) {
            radius7 = 60 - (height - 400)/20;
          }else {
            radius7 = 32 - (height/100);
          }
          var radi_result = `#section_2_inner {
          border-radius: 0% 0% 45% 5% / 50% 50% `+ radius7 +`% 5%;
        }`;
          var style = document.createElement('style');
          style.innerHTML = radi_result;
          document.head.appendChild(style);
        </script>


        <div class="section-2-inner-content">

        <!-- section 2 content -->
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2 class="title">Section 2</h2>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-6">
                <article class="">
                  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                  </p>
                </article>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <article class="">
                  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                  </p>
                </article>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <article class="">
                  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                  </p>
                </article>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <article class="">
                  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                  </p>
                </article>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <article class="">
                  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                  </p>
                </article>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- content end -->

        </div>
      </div>
      <img id="arc-2" src="arc-2.png" alt="" width="100%" height="auto">
    </div>

  </div>

  <img class="food" src="food-2.png" alt="" width="30%" height="auto">

</section>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your solution shows this output:
http://clawsandfins.com/sof_images/rabin_1.png
Which is not what I want..

Answer (score 0):

```
  body{
      background-image: url(bg.png);
      background-size: contain;
      background-position: bottom;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
  }

  .logo{
      position: absolute;
      left: 100px;
      top: 100px;
      z-index: 999;
  }

  .bg-1, .bg-2, .bg-3{
      padding: 100px 0;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: bottom;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
  .bg-1{
      background-image: url(bg-111.png);
      padding-top: 0;
      z-index: 50;
  }

  .bg-1 .title{
      color: #ffc602;
      font-size: 77px;
      margin-bottom: 50px:
  }
  .bg-1 .sub-title{
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 34px;
      margin-bottom: 70px;
  }

  .bg-2 .food{
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0px;
      z-index: 200;
  }
  .bg-3 .food{
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      bottom: -25px;
      z-index: 200;
  }

  .about h2 {
      color: #ffc602;
      font-size: 55px;
      margin-bottom: 50px:
  }
  .about p {
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 15px;
      line-height: 1.8;
      margin-bottom: 50px:
  }

  #section_2 .title, #section_3 .title{
    font-size: 55px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }

  .article-1{
    padding: 100px;
    z-index: 10;
  }

  section{
      position: relative;
  }
  #section_2{
    margin-top: -450px
  }

  #section_2 .section-2-outer{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }

  .section-2-inner-content{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 2%;
  }
  #arc-2{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -120px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
  }

  #arc_3{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -110px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
  }
```

Comment: if you could show me the output of this code that would be help me understand it!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1.make div for background as parent   set pattern background
2. make div under set backgorund layer-1

3. adjust background using css

Comment: I see! you explained it but can you show me the output in the form of working code..

Comment: @AbdulHadi yes i can make separate svg for it.

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
  }
  body{
    margin: 0px;
  }
  img{
    width: 100%;
  }
  section{
    position: relative;
  }
  section svg {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
  }

  section .content{
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0px;
      z-index: 1;
  }

  section .top-clip {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
  }

  section {
    /*background-size: 100% auto;*/
  }

  section #pattern_top {
      fill: transparent;
  }

  section #pattern_bottom {
      fill: transparent;
  }

  .pattern-prev-clip,.pattern-bottom-clip{
    /*background-size: 100% auto;*/
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .content > div{
      display: block !important;
    }

    .content .cnt-1{
      max-width: 100% !important;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://demo.zhardsoft.com/arc-pattern-3/svg-inject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var svgInjectElements=[];
  var tt=0;
  
  SVGInject.setOptions({
      useCache: false, // no caching
      copyAttributes: false, // do not copy attributes from `<img>` to `<svg>`
      makeIdsUnique: false, // do not make ids used within the SVG unique
      afterInject: function(img, svg) {
        svgInjectElements[parseInt($(img).attr('img-arc'))]=svg;

        if(tt > $('.img-arc').length){
          svgInjectElements.forEach(function(svg){
            loadSVGInject(svg);
          })
        }
        tt++;

      },
    });

  function loadSVGInject(svg){
    var svgElm=$(svg);
    var parentSection=svgElm.parents('.section');
    var prevSection=svgElm.parents('.section').prev();
    // svgElm.parents('section').find('svg #pattern_bottom').wrap('<defs></defs>').wrap('<clipPath id="my-clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"></clipPath>');
    var clipID=parentSection.attr('data-clip-id');
    var prevClipID=prevSection.attr('data-clip-id');

    parentSection.find('svg #pattern_bottom_clip').attr('id','pattern_bottom_clip_'+clipID);
    parentSection.find('svg #pattern_top_clip').attr('id','pattern_top_clip_'+clipID);

    var svgHeight=svgElm.height();
    parentSection.css({'background-position-y':'-'+svgHeight+'px'});
    
    parentSection.find('svg').css({'top':'-'+(svgHeight-1)+'px',});

    if(prevSection.find('.pattern-prev-clip').length<=0){
      parentSection.find('svg #pattern_top').attr('transform','scale('+(1/svgElm[0].viewBox.baseVal.width)+','+(1/svgElm[0].viewBox.baseVal.height)+')');
      var bgPrev=prevSection.css('background-image');
      var patternPrevClip=document.createElement('div');
          $(patternPrevClip).addClass('pattern-prev-clip').css({'-webkit-clip-path': 'url(#pattern_top_clip_'+clipID+')','clip-path': 'url(#pattern_top_clip_'+clipID+')'});
          // $(patternPrevClip).addClass('pattern-prev-clip').css('background-image', bgPrev);
      prevSection.append(patternPrevClip);

      var blockContent=document.createElement('div');
          $(blockContent).addClass('block-content');
      $(patternPrevClip).before(blockContent);
    }


    var baseHeight=svgElm.height()/svgElm[0].viewBox.baseVal.height;
    // console.log(svgElm.height()+" - "+svgElm[0].viewBox.baseVal.height);
    var ppcHeightTop=parseInt(parentSection.find('svg #pattern_top')[0].getAttribute('height'))*baseHeight;
    var ppcHeightBottom=parseInt(parentSection.find('svg #pattern_bottom')[0].getAttribute('height'))*baseHeight;

    if(prevSection.find('svg').length>0){
      var basePrevHeight=prevSection.find('svg').height()/prevSection.find('svg')[0].viewBox.baseVal.height;
      var ppcPrevHeightBottom=parseInt(prevSection.find('svg #pattern_bottom')[0].getAttribute('height'))*basePrevHeight;
    }

    
    // parentSection.css({'top':(svgElm.height()-ppcHeightTop)+'px'});
    prevSection.find('.pattern-prev-clip').css({'height':svgHeight+'px','top':'-'+(svgHeight-1)+'px'}).attr('height',svgHeight);

    if(parentSection.find('.pattern-bottom-clip').length<=0){
      parentSection.find('svg #pattern_bottom').attr('transform','scale('+(1/svgElm[0].viewBox.baseVal.width)+','+(1/svgElm[0].viewBox.baseVal.height)+')');
      var bg=parentSection.css('background-image');
      var patternTopClip=document.createElement('div');
          $(patternTopClip).addClass('top-clip pattern-bottom-clip').css({'background-image': bg,'-webkit-clip-path': 'url(#pattern_bottom_clip_'+clipID+')','clip-path': 'url(#pattern_bottom_clip_'+clipID+')'});
      svgElm.before(patternTopClip);
    }
    parentSection.find('.pattern-bottom-clip').css({'height':svgHeight+'px','top':'-'+(svgHeight-1)+'px'}).attr('height',svgHeight);

    // console.log("prev section id: "+(ppcPrevHeightBottom ?? 0));
    // console.log(((svgElm.height()-ppcHeightTop) + prevSection.find('.pattern-prev-clip').height()));
    // prevSection.find('.content').css('min-height',prevSection.height() - ((svgElm.height()-ppcHeightTop)) );
    // 
    // prevSection.css('min-height', (prevSection.find('.pattern-prev-clip').height() + prevSection.find('.content').outerHeight()) - (ppcPrevHeightBottom ?? 0) );
    var prevBlockContentHeight=(prevSection.find('.content').outerHeight() - ppcHeightTop) - (ppcPrevHeightBottom ?? 0);
    // prevBlockContentHeight=prevBlockContentHeight>200?prevBlockContentHeight:200;
    prevSection.find('.block-content').css('height', prevBlockContentHeight).attr('height',prevBlockContentHeight);
    parentSection.find('.content').css('top','-'+ppcHeightBottom+'px');
    // parentSection.find('.pattern-bottom-clip').css('background-size','auto '+parentSection.find('.pattern-prev-clip').attr('height')+'px');
    // console.log(prevSection.find('.pattern-prev-clip').css('height'));
    // prevSection.find('.pattern-bottom-clip').css('background-size','auto '+(parseFloat(prevSection.find('.pattern-prev-clip').attr('height')) + parseFloat(prevSection.find('.block-content').attr('height')) )+'px');
    var bgPrevHeight=(
                    parseFloat(prevSection.find('.pattern-prev-clip').attr('height'))
                    + 
                    parseFloat(prevSection.find('.block-content').attr('height')) 
                    +
                    parseFloat( (prevSection.find('.pattern-bottom-clip').attr('height') ?? 0) )
                  );
    prevSection.css({'background-size':'auto '+ bgPrevHeight +'px'});
    prevSection.find('.pattern-bottom-clip').css('background-size','auto '+ bgPrevHeight +'px');

    if($('.section').last().attr('data-clip-id') == clipID){
      if(parentSection.find('.block-content').length<=0){
        var blockContent=document.createElement('div');
            $(blockContent).addClass('block-content');
        parentSection.append(blockContent);
      }
      var lastBlockContent=(parentSection.find('.content').outerHeight() - ppcHeightBottom);
          lastBlockContent=(lastBlockContent > 0 ? lastBlockContent : 100);
      parentSection.find('.block-content').css('min-height',  lastBlockContent ).attr('height',lastBlockContent);

      var bgHeight=(
                      parseFloat(parentSection.find('.block-content').attr('height')) 
                      +
                      parseFloat(parentSection.find('.pattern-bottom-clip').attr('height'))
                    );
      parentSection.css({'background-size':'auto '+ bgHeight +'px'});
      parentSection.find('.pattern-bottom-clip').css('background-size','auto '+ bgHeight +'px');
    }
    // prevSection.css('min-height',prevSection.height()-(svgElm.height()-ppcHeightTop));


    var prevSvgHeight=prevSection.find('svg').height();
    if(prevSection.find('.pattern-bottom-clip').nextAll('.pattern-prev-clip').length>0){
      $(patternPrevClip).css('background-position-y', '-'+prevSvgHeight+'px');
    }else{
      $(patternPrevClip).addClass('pattern-prev-clip').css('background-position-y', '-'+prevSection.find('.content').innerHeight()+'px');
    }

  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.img-arc').each(function(){
      SVGInject(this);
    })
  })

  $(window).on('resize',function(){
    svgInjectElements.forEach(function(svg){
      loadSVGInject(svg);
    })
    // $('section svg').each(function(){
    //   var svgElm=$(this);
    //   var svgHeight=svgElm.height();
    //   svgElm.parents('section').css({'background-position-y':'-'+svgHeight+'px'});
    //   svgElm.parents('section').find('.arc-overlay').css({'height':svgHeight+'px','top':'-'+(svgHeight-1)+'px'});
    //   svgElm.parents('section').find('svg').css({'top':'-'+(svgHeight-1)+'px',});
    // })
  })
  
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="section" data-clip-id="1" style="background-image: url(https://demo.zhardsoft.com/arc-pattern-3/pattern_bg1.jpg);">
      <div class="content">
        <div style="padding: 0 40px;padding-top: 50px">
          <div class="cnt-1" style="color: #EBEBEB;padding: 0 40px;">
            <h1>ECOLOGICAL PRODUCTION</h1>
          <div style="padding: 20px;float: right"><img src="https://demo.zhardsoft.com/arc-pattern-3/img1.png" style="max-width: 300px"></div>
          We recycle all organic waste we produce, also, we obtain organic waste from other farms, restaurants, and food markets. The organic waste we collect allows a particular larva from the Hermetia illucens species, known commonly as black soldier fly larva (BSFL), to feeds on it and grow fatter. When the larva has developed to a pupa, it is cleaned, cooked and grided to a paste used as a high-quality protein and lipids perfectly suited as ecological animal feed, reducing the need for wild-sourced feed ingredients such as fishmeal which contributes to the global overfishing.</div>
        </div>
        <div style="padding: 0 40px;padding-top: 50px">
          <div class="cnt-1" style="color: #EBEBEB;padding: 0 40px;">
          <div style="padding: 20px;float: left"><img src="https://demo.zhardsoft.com/arc-pattern-3/img1.png" style="max-width: 500px"></div>
          We recycle all organic waste we produce, also, we obtain organic waste from other farms, restaurants, and food markets. The organic waste we collect allows a particular larva from the Hermetia illucens species, known commonly as black soldier fly larva (BSFL), to feeds on it and grow fatter. When the larva has developed to a pupa, it is cleaned, cooked and grided to a paste used as a high-quality protein and lipids perfectly suited as ecological animal feed, reducing the need for wild-sourced feed ingredients such as fishmeal which contributes to the global overfishing.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="section" data-clip-id="2" style="background-image: url(https://demo.zhardsoft.com/arc-pattern-3/pattern_bg2.jpg);">
      <div class="content">
        <div style="padding: 0 40px;padding-bottom: 60px">
          <div class="cnt-1" style="color: #EBEBEB;text-align: right;flex-grow: 1">
              <h1 style="color: #FDC403">LOCAL COMMUNITY<br>ENGAGEMENT.</h1>
            It is in our core believe that if you benefit the local community, the people there will add value to your business as well. For every site we establish a manufacturing facility, our project will add value to the community as whole. We will provide jobs for hundreds of local residents with positions available within our production, sales, administration, and management teams. We will also offer hundreds of local farmers opportunities to join our supply network, providing training, coaching, and financial support to help them adapt to a more intensive and efficient farming system. Through our research and development, anything learned or discovered will be shared with our farmers to produce more efficiently and a healthier product. One among many different local benefitting activities, is that we will arrange cleanup days where we offer students an extra income for their effort as well as courses in environment know-how and teach them the importance of keeping the environment healthy.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- <img src="arc_1.svg" onload="SVGInject(this);"/> -->
      <img img-arc="1" class="img-arc" src="https://demo.zhardsoft.com/arc-pattern-3/arc_1.svg"/>
    </section>
    <section class="section" data-clip-id="3" style="background-image: url(https://demo.zhardsoft.com/arc-pattern-3/pattern_bg3.jpg);">
      <div class="content">
        <div style="padding: 0 40px;padding-top: 50px">
          <div class="cnt-1" style="color: #EBEBEB;text-align: center;flex-grow: 1">
              <h1 style="color: #FDC403">LOCAL COMMUNITY<br>ENGAGEMENT. 2</h1>
              It is in our core believe that if you benefit the local community, the people there will add value to your business as well. For every site we establish a manufacturing facility, our project will add value to the community as whole. We will provide jobs for hundreds of local residents with positions available within our production, sales, administration, and management teams. We will also offer hundreds of local farmers opportunities to join our supply network, providing training, coaching, and financial support to help them adapt to a more intensive and efficient farming system. Through our research and development, anything learned or discovered will be shared with our farmers to produce more efficiently and a healthier product. One among many different local benefitting activities, is that we will arrange cleanup days where we offer students an extra income for their effort as well as courses in environment know-how and teach them the importance of keeping the environment healthy.
              <img src="https://demo.zhardsoft.com/arc-pattern-3/img1.png" style="max-width: 400px">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img img-arc="2" class="img-arc" src="https://demo.zhardsoft.com/arc-pattern-3/arc_2.svg"/>
    </section>
    <section class="section" data-clip-id="4" style="background-image: url(https://demo.zhardsoft.com/arc-pattern-3/pattern_bg4.jpg);">
      <div class="content">
        <div style="padding: 0 40px;padding-top: 50px">
          <div class="cnt-1" style="color: #EBEBEB;text-align: left;">
            <p><h1 style="color: #FDC403">LOCAL COMMUNITY<br/>ENGAGEMENT. 3</h1>
              <img src="https://demo.zhardsoft.com/arc-pattern-3/img1.png" style="float: right;max-width: 500px;padding: 0 40px">
              It is in our core believe that if you benefit the local community, the people there will add value to your business as well. For every site we establish a manufacturing facility, our project will add value to the community as whole. We will provide jobs for hundreds of local residents with positions available within our production, sales, administration, and management teams. We will also offer hundreds of local farmers opportunities to join our supply network, providing training, coaching, and financial support to help them adapt to a more intensive and efficient farming system. Through our research and development, anything learned or discovered will be shared with our farmers to produce more efficiently and a healthier product. One among many different local benefitting activities, is that we will arrange cleanup days where we offer students an extra income for their effort as well as courses in environment know-how and teach them the importance of keeping the environment healthy.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img img-arc="3" class="img-arc" src="https://demo.zhardsoft.com/arc-pattern-3/arc_3.svg"/>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code that I have improved from my previous post, please check it

Answer (score 0):

**

I'm Can Solving Your Problem But I want to have the svg so that I know how to make a clip path for it, so I want you to send it to me, and this is the solution. You want it to be dynamic, but first I have to have my svg and thank you

```css
section {
    position: relative;
}
.arc {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
}
.arc::after {
    content: url(arc1.svg);
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(130deg);
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <section style="background:black;">
            Content goes here...
        </section>
        <div class="arc"></div>
        <section style="background:grey">
            Content goes here...
        </section>
        <div class="arc"></div>
    </div>
```

**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> ---

```css
body {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.global_container_ {
  float: none;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 1280px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.rectangle-10-copy-holder {
  height: 3623px;
  position: relative;
  width: 1280px;
  background-image: url(brick2.jpg);
}

.col {
  min-height: 3095px;
  padding: 0 0 134px;
  position: relative;
  width: 1280px;
  background: url(images/layer_10.png) no-repeat;
}
.wrapper-3 {
  height: 2601px;
  position: relative;
  width: 1280px;
  background-image: url(brick.jpg);
}

.elements {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("brick.jpg");
}

.shape-7-copy-2 {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1100px;
  margin-left: -405px;
}
.shape-1 {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1026px;
  margin-left: -640px;
}
.about-us {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 827px;
  width: 1070px;
  margin-left: -520px;
}
.ellipse-2-copy {
  float: left;
  height: 462px;
  margin: 18px 71px 0 0;
  width: 462px;
  border: 20px solid #e0330a;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;

  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: url(images/food.png) no-repeat;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -13.365098px -6.809857px 24px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.62);
  -moz-box-shadow: -13.365098px -6.809857px 24px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.62);
  box-shadow: -13.365098px -6.809857px 24px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.62);
}
.col-2 {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
}
.text {
  color: #ffc602;
  font-family: Barlow, sans-serif;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
.text-2 {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Barlow, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
.text-3 {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2470px;
  color: #ffc600;
  font-family: Barlow, sans-serif;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: right;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.ecological {
  height: 1385px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1108px;
  width: 1280px;
  background: url(images/shape_5_copy_3.png) no-repeat 0 130px;
  margin-left: -640px;
}
.shape-5-copy-4-holder {
  left: 50%;
  padding: 4px 0 17px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 315px;
  width: 1280px;
  background: url(images/shape_5_copy_4.png) no-repeat;
  margin-left: -640px;
}
.shape-5-copy-5 {
  display: block;
}
.shape-5-copy {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 230px;
  margin-left: -640px;
}
.shape-5-copy-2-holder {
  left: 50%;
  padding: 1px 0 14px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 1280px;
  background: url(images/shape_5_copy_2.png) no-repeat;
  margin-left: -640px;
}
.shape-5-copy-7-holder {
  padding: 149px 0 17px;
  position: relative;
  width: 1280px;
  background: url(images/shape_5_copy_7.png) no-repeat;
}
.col-3 {
  min-height: 1166px;
  padding: 34px 0 33px;
  position: relative;
  width: 1280px;
  background: url(images/shape_5.png) no-repeat;
}
.wrapper-6 {
  height: 618px;
  left: 40.5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 1199px;
}
.ellipse-7 {
  height: 500px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 500px;
  border-top: 20px solid #e0330a;
  border-left: 20px solid #e0330a;
  border-bottom: 20px solid #e0330a;
  border-right: 20px solid #e0330a;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: url(images/food3.png) no-repeat -8px -5px;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -13.365098px -6.809857px 5px 0 rgba(155, 6, 6, 0.61);
  -moz-box-shadow: -13.365098px -6.809857px 5px 0 rgba(155, 6, 6, 0.61);
  box-shadow: -13.365098px -6.809857px 5px 0 rgba(155, 6, 6, 0.61);
  margin-left: 70.5px;
}

.text-4 {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 420px;

  width: 730px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 32px;
  margin-left: -595.5px;
}
.text-5 {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 346px;
  font-family: Barlow, sans-serif;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-left: -570.5px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.text-6 {
  float: right;
  margin: 75px 0 0;
  width: 676px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 32px;
}
.ellipse-3-copy {
  float: left;
  height: 404px;
  margin: 18px 71px 0 0;
  width: 404px;
  border: 20px solid #e0330a;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;

  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: url(images/food2.png) no-repeat 1px 1px;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -13.365098px -6.809857px 24px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.62);
  -moz-box-shadow: -13.365098px -6.809857px 24px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.62);
  box-shadow: -13.365098px -6.809857px 24px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.62);
}
.ellipse-4-copy-2 {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -345px;
}
.ellipse-4-copy-3 {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -347px;
}
.ellipse-4-copy-holder {
  left: 50%;
  padding: 0 0 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 1039px;
  background: url(images/ellipse_4_copy.png) no-repeat;
  margin-left: -399px;
}
.ellipse-4-copy-4-holder {
  left: 11.5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 0 23px;
  position: relative;
  width: 1016px;
  background: url(images/ellipse_4_copy_4.png) no-repeat;
}
.ellipse-4-holder {
  left: 26.5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 0 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 963px;
  background: url(images/ellipse_4.png) no-repeat;
}
.ellipse-4 {
  display: block;
  left: 18px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.ellipse-1-copy-3 {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -640px;
}
.ellipse-1-copy-5 {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -640px;
}
.ellipse-1 {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -640px;
}
.ellipse-1-copy-2 {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -640px;
}
.text-7 {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 528px;
  color: #ffc602;
  font-size: 77.31771px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 82px;
  margin-left: -552px;
}
.text-8 {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 627px;
  font-family: Barlow, sans-serif;
  font-size: 34px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-left: -554px;
}
.layer-16 {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 58px;
  margin-left: -516px;
}

.row-5 {
  left: 25.5px;
  margin: 37px auto 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 1229px;
}

.text-10 {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 620px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-left: -100px;
}

.wrapper-8 {
  float: left;
  margin: 13px 0 0;
  padding: 13px 0 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 130px;
  background: url(images/vector_smart_object_copy__12.jpg) no-repeat;
}

.new {
  height: 829px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2794px;
  width: 1280px;
  background: url(images/vector_smart_object_5.png) no-repeat;
  margin-left: -640px;
}

.shape-9-holder {
  height: 715px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 114px;
  width: 1280px;
  background: url(images/shape_9.png) no-repeat;
  margin-left: -640px;
}
.vector-smart-object-5 {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 247px;
  margin-left: -640px;
}
.vector-smart-object-copy-24-holder {
  left: 50%;
  padding: 105px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 210px;
  width: 1280px;
  background: url(images/vector_smart_object_copy__19.png) no-repeat;
  margin-left: -640px;
}
.vector-smart-object-holder {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 70px 0 0;
  position: relative;
  right: 48px;
  width: 1184px;
  background: url(images/vector_smart_object_7.png) no-repeat;
}
.shape-8 {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  right: 171.5px;
}
.layer-17 {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 95px;
  margin-top: -170px;
}
.circle {
  height: 692px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  width: 985px;
  margin-left: -574px;
}
.group-2 {
  height: 438px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 438px;
  margin-left: -492.5px;
}

.ellipse-8-copy {
  height: 417px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 417px;
  border: 20px solid #e0330a;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;

  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: url(images/food4.png) no-repeat -3px -3px;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -13.365098px -6.809857px 24px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.62);
  -moz-box-shadow: -13.365098px -6.809857px 24px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.62);
  box-shadow: -13.365098px -6.809857px 24px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.62);
  margin-left: -219px;
}
.group-2-copy {
  height: 330px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 182px;
  width: 330px;
  margin-left: 162.5px;
}

.ellipse-8-copy-2 {
  height: 320px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 320px;
  border: 20px solid #ffc602;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: url(images/food5.png) no-repeat 2px 1px;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  margin-left: -165px;
}
.group-2-copy-2 {
  height: 430px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 262px;
  width: 430px;
  margin-left: -194.5px;
}

.ellipse-8-copy-3 {
  height: 415px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 415px;
  border: 20px solid #ff4600;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: url(images/food6.png) no-repeat 2px 1px;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;

  margin-left: -215px;
}


.sile{
  text-align: left;
  
  
  }
  
  #mySpan{
  writing-mode: vertical-lr; 
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 20px;
 
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>food</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- <div class="center">
  <li>HOME</li>
  <li>PRODUCT</li>
  <li>PRICING</li>
  <li>CONTACT US</li>
</div> -->
  <div class="global_container_">
    <div class="bg-banner-about">
      <div class="rectangle-10-copy-holder">
        <div class="banner group">
          <div class="col08">
            <div class="wrapper-3">

              <img class="shape-7-copy-2" src="images/shape_7_copy_2.png" alt="" width="1045" height="818">
              <img class="shape-1" src="images/shape_1.png" alt="" width="755" height="503">
              <div class="about-us group">
                <div class="ellipse-2-copy"></div>
                <div class="col-2">
                  <h1 class="text">ABOUT US</h1>
                  <h3 class="text-2">
                    Pete's Claws and Fins is a high-tech producer of ecological seafood. We use
                    state-of-the-art, highly computerized equipment to monitor and manage our seafood to ensure it is of
                    the highest possible quality. All equipment we use is developed by ourselves in-house. We are the
                    only company operating such high-tech equipment. The company started its research and development
                    2016 by Peter Persson, a Swedish inventor who has designed and built automated and
                    computer-controlled machines and robots for over 30 years. Peter has over the years developed an
                    increasing personal interest for natural and unprocessed food, and though he could make difference
                    with help of his high-tech knowhow.
                  </h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <p class="text-3">Local Community<br>Engagement.</p>
              <div class="ecological">
                <div class="shape-5-copy-4-holder">
                  <img class="shape-5-copy-5" src="images/shape_5_copy_5.png" alt="" width="1280" height="1049">
                </div>
                <img class="shape-5-copy" src="images/shape_5_copy.png" alt="" width="1280" height="1066">
                <div class="shape-5-copy-2-holder">
                  <div class="shape-5-copy-7-holder">
                    <div class="col-3">
                      <div class="wrapper-6">

                        <div class="ellipse-7"></div>
                        <p class="text-4">All our seafoods are ecologically produced. Our endeavor is not using
                          resources from the wildlife. We are only using farm-raised animals for our production. Our
                          production is free from using harmful chemicals that can contaminate the environment or the
                          food products we produce. Instead, we use natural minerals and bacteria to break down our
                          waste products into harmless, biodegradable compounds.</p>
                        <p class="text-5">Ecological production</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row group">
                        <div class="ellipse-3-copy"></div>
                        <p class="text-6">We recycle all organic waste we produce, also, we obtain organic waste from
                          other farms, restaurants, and food markets. The organic waste we collect allows a particular
                          larva from the <em class="text-style">Hermetia illucens</em> species, known commonly as black
                          soldier fly larva (BSFL), to feeds on it and grow fatter. When the larva has developed to a
                          pupa, it is cleaned, cooked and grided to a paste used as a high-quality protein and lipids
                          perfectly suited as ecological animal feed, reducing the need for wild-sourced feed
                          ingredients such as fishmeal which contributes to the global overfishing.</p>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
              <img class="ellipse-4-copy-2" src="images/ellipse_4_copy_2.png" alt="" width="985" height="686">
              <img class="ellipse-4-copy-3" src="images/ellipse_4_copy_3.png" alt="" width="987" height="676">
              <div class="ellipse-4-copy-holder">

                <div class="ellipse-4-copy-4-holder">
                  <div class="ellipse-4-holder">

                    <img class="ellipse-4" src="images/food1.png" alt="" width="927" height="611">
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
              <img class="ellipse-1-copy-3" src="images/ellipse_1_copy_3.png" alt="" width="630" height="464">
              <img class="ellipse-1-copy-5" src="images/ellipse_1_copy_5.png" alt="" width="601" height="430">
              <img class="ellipse-1" src="images/ellipse_1.png" alt="" width="555" height="446">

              <p class="text-7">We Are Using</p>
              <p class="text-8">tech and artificial intelligence (AI) To produce ecological food.</p>

              <img class="layer-16" src="images/logo2.png" alt="" width="222" height="207">

             <div class="side"><span id="mySpan"> CONTACT&nbsp;US &nbsp; &nbsp; PRICING &nbsp; &nbsp;  PRODUCT &nbsp; &nbsp; HOME&nbsp; &nbsp;</span>
             </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-5 group">
              <div class="wrapper-9">

                <p class="text-10">It is in our core believe that if you benefit the local community, the people there
                  will add value to your business as well. For every site we establish a manufacturing facility, our
                  project will add value to the community as whole. We will provide jobs for hundreds of local residents
                  with positions available within our production, sales, administration, and management teams. We will
                  also offer hundreds of local farmers opportunities to join our supply network, providing training,
                  coaching, and financial support to help them adapt to a more intensive and efficient farming system.
                  Through our research and development, anything learned or discovered will be shared with our farmers
                  to produce more efficiently and a healthier product. One among many different local benefitting
                  activities, is that we will arrange cleanup days where we offer students an extra income for their
                  effort as well as courses in environment know-how and teach them the importance of keeping the
                  environment healthy.</p>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>


        <div class="new">
          <div class="shape-9-holder">

            <img class="vector-smart-object-5" src="images/vector_smart_object_6.png" alt="" width="1276" height="468">
            <div class="vector-smart-object-copy-24-holder">
              <div class="vector-smart-object-holder">
                <img class="shape-8" src="images/shape_8.png" alt="" width="841" height="330">
                <img class="layer-17" src="images/logo1.png" alt="" width="140" height="140">
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="circle">
            <div class="group-2">

              <div class="ellipse-8-copy"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="group-2-copy">


              <div class="ellipse-8-copy-2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="group-2-copy-2">


              <div class="ellipse-8-copy-3"></div>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

</body>

</h>
```

Heading

Comment: Code only answers are considered low quality. but file send not option Without sufficient explaination, your answer is hard to understand. If the OP can't understand your answer, then he also won't be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it would be worthless to him/her. Please add a sufficient explaination of your possible